# Return jet not working in pool

Tags: pool

I have an Inground pool and  I have 7 return jets in my pool. 6 of 7 are working flawlessly with excellent pressure coming out of them with no air bubbles. EXCEPT  my 7th jet that is right underneath my skimmer does not work. I have gone on many forums and troubleshooted many times and I still can't get the thing to work
Here's what I have tried so far
1. Covered all the other jets eyeballs up and hope the pressure builds to push out anything that is in there (no luck) also when I did do this, the pressure (18psi) remained the same 
2. I've drained my pool twice and took off ALL the jet eyeballs and cleaned out the pipe with a wet vac (no luck)
3. I've bought expensive drain cleaner for the pool  (no luck)
4. I've checked my D.E filter and replaced with new filters (no luck)
5. Checked all my skimmer baskets and cleaned out the pump motor (no luck)
6. I've changed out all my o-rings (no luck)

I have visually checked for leaks everywhere and the only leak I had found was by my brominator but it isn't a continuous leak and I don't think this would be enough for a single return, to not work?
And the way they designed and put in the pool they didn't install separate manifolds for each return  so I'm out of the luck with that.
So at this point I'm pretty much all out of options unless someone else can point me in the right direction?

Comment: How certain are you that it's a return jet?  Typically those are not located "right underneath a skimmer".  If the pool is new to you, keep in mind just because it has a jet eyeball attached to it doesn't mean the last guy did it right.  Do you have solar water heating in a climate that freezes?  If you do it might be a gravity drain for the solar collector water.  It might also be connected to a filler sump well.

Comment: Post pictures of the pool and equipment pad for better answers.  I suspect it's not a return jet.

Comment: This is an indoor heated pool, and I had a plumber come out and look at it for me, and turns out it isn't a return! Not sure why or whoever put a jet eyeball on this is beyond me.

Comment: Tyson is on track. Many years ago I did pools and they use the same jets for the solar return if not on the suction side of the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Take a conventional garden hose and shove it in the faulty orifice.  If the fit is loose, try and shove something into the hole around the hose... and.... turn on the spigot!

One of more things will happen:

1) You'll see water coming out of some other area.
2) The water will begin spraying back at you.
3) You'll realize that pool installers are idiots.

If the water begins pouring out somewhere else, it will provide a clue of how the plumbing is ran. If it sprays back at you immediately and almost no water pours back out of the pipe after you remove the hose it is saying there is a blockage very near you... or it's capped off behind the wall.  If it sprays back at you after 30 seconds, it means the pipe is blocked/capped farther in.  When you pull the hose out, does a lot of water drain back out?

It is theoretically possible to have a line get clogged... but it would have to be from a build-up of D.E. material or some other mineral deposit, as nothing big enough in itself to clog a line would ever have been able to make it through the pump strainer.  I know when I turn on my 3 HP pump full throttle it'll blow little crusted pieces of D.E. out of the return lines once in a while... so I suppose it is theoretically possible that some of those chunks could build up on themselves.

I am a licensed general contractor and have a great deal of experience in plumbing, electrical, and concrete.  With that being said, the 30,000 gallon gunite pool that I inherited with the house I bought two years ago has cost me a great many brain cells.  It is readily apparent that pool contractors aren't terribly good at any of the three.  To make matters worse, pools don't have to have any permits here.... thus allowing the horrible mechanical craftsmanship to continue.

Trying to logically analyze an idiot tends to crash my mental operating system.  "Does not compute.  Does not compute.  Does not compute".